# Text Search using jQuery on XML data loaded with Ajax GET Method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I have a html page which displays a table of XML data retrieved using the ajax GET method. I have created an input box in which I want the user to be able to input a program title and for that program title to be highlighted and possibly for the other programs to fade out. This is the jQuery code I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var sky1 = 'https://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00533474/workspace/COM554/assignment_2/CR/sky_one.xml',
            bbc1 = 'https://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00533474/workspace/COM554/assignment_2/CR/bbc1.xml',
            skyn = 'https://scm.ulster.ac.uk/~B00533474/workspace/COM554/assignment_2/CR/sky_news.xml';
        $.when(
            $.ajax( sky1 ),
            $.ajax( bbc1 ),
            $.ajax( skyn )
        ).then(function( skyone, bbcone, skynews ) {

    $("#filter").keyup(function parseXml(){

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

        // Loop through the programme list
        $('programme',sky1).each(function() {

            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();

            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });

        // Update the count
        var numberItems = count;
        $("#filter-count").text("Number of Comments = "+count);
    });
});
        });
```

And the XML looks like this: (only a snippet):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<channel id="sky_one" source="Sky" date="25/11/2014">
  <programme>
<desc>Tony's motorcycle bursts into flames between his legs while town planner Liz is left in agony after her half-tonne horse bolts and lands on top of her. Also in HD</desc>
<title>The Real A &amp; E</title>
<end>0630</end>
<start>0600</start>
  </programme>
  <programme>
<desc>When Justin tries to detach a winch rope from a rock face during a charity event, a loose boulder falls on his pelvis. But with such rocky terrain, the Air Ambulance is unable to land. Also in HD</desc>
<title>The Real A &amp; E</title>
<end>0700</end>
<start>0630</start>
  </programme>
  <programme>
<desc>Temperatures rise as big boss Ken and legions of angry bakers take to the streets to protest against the 'Pasty Tax', before Greggs faces its biggest-ever crisis. (S1, ep 4) Also in HD</desc>
<title>Greggs: More Than Meats The Pie</title>
<end>0800</end>
<start>0700</start>
  </programme>
  <programme>
<subtitle>That's Lobstertainment</subtitle>
<desc>Bender and Zoidberg travel to Hollywood in search of stardom. (S3, ep 8)</desc>
<title>Futurama</title>
<end>0830</end>
<start>0800</start>
  </programme>
  <programme>
</channel>
```

If any one could help me out or point me in the right direction that'd be great!